# Regex to match an the value of a json entry that may contains square brackets []

Tags: regex

I have a json that have the following structure:

```
{
  test1:[value1, value2],
  test2:[value3, value4],
  .....
}
```

I am trying to match the key pair value `test1:[value1, value2]`.  The issue is that I do not always know what the value of the key `test1` is. Also, sometimes it might not be an array but just a value.  I tried this

```
"test1":(\[{1})?([^]]+)(\]{1})?(\,)?
```

but it only works if the value of the key`test1` is a array only. If if remove the square bracket, it will also match the second key `test2`. The other issue is that I am using a tool that do not have a json parser

How can go about this?

Comment: Why does this need to be a regex solution? Couldn't you just convert to a dictionary and reference test1 that way? [This should do what you want it to, but I still don't think regex is the right choice](https://regex101.com/r/0J7ZEm/1)

Comment: Because I need to match the whole entry(key-value pair)  and not just the value

Comment: If your input is valid JSON then use a JSON tool or library to parse it into data structures specific to the language. What language do you use?

Comment: regex can do the job, but I need to know a little more: are there ever arrays nested in the array, eg `"test":[value1, [value2, value3], value4]` and/or are the ever square brackets in the values, eg `"test1":[value1, "foo ] bar", value3]`. A regex can still be found if these things are there, but it becomes very complicated if they are ther, so "no" is there preferred answer.

Comment: The value can be at most an array. So the value of the entry is either a value or an array. Nothing more

Comment: @user3841581 and is it possible that any of the values are string that contain a right square bracket, eg `"test1":"foo ] bar"`?

Comment: @Bohemian no. values can be regular strings or strings that may contain array with element that are http/https addresses

Comment: @user3841581 voila: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033164/256196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alternation to cover both cases:

```
"test1"\s*:\s*(?:\[[^]]*]|[^,}]+)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/hzgil7xWK6XfsP).

Breaking it down:

- `"test1"\s*:\s*` allows for spaces around the colon
- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group
- `...|...` is a alternation - like a logic `OR`
- `[^]]` is any character that's not a right square bracket
- `\[[^]]*]` is any number of characters that are not a right square brackets, surrounded by square brackets
- `[^,}]+` is any number of characters that are not commas or closing braces (in case the matched term is the last json key:value pair

Comment: This work quite well; but does not take into account if the entry is the last element of the json. It also matches the closing brace of the json

Comment: ce n'est pas une problème

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions cannot match nested JSON structures.

Just use a proper JSON parser instead. Your code will become both simpler and more correct.

A general reminder: regular expressions can only solve a very limited set of problems. Therefore, whenever you ask for a regular expression, you should rather ask for solving the problem without involving regular expressions at all. Just solve the problem, no matter how.

Comment: IIIig, the tool I am using do not have a parser